# Wordpress using $_GET in sql query

Tags: php, sql, get, wordpress

I am trying to run a "sql query" which needs a post result. I keep getting this error:

`Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in ../includes/functions.php on line 43`

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['slug'])){
    function get_slug() {
        $slug = 'home';
        return $slug;
    }
} else {
    function get_slug() {
        $sql = "SELECT slug FROM wp_content WHERE slug='".$_GET['slug']."'";
        while ($result = $wpdb->get_results($sql)) {
            $slug = $result['slug'];
            return $slug;
        }
    }   
}
```

I think that the problem is in the `$_GET`. I've tried the "wordpress function" `get_query_var('slug')` instead and still the same error occurs.

Comment: Scope issue.. Pass `$wpdb` to your `get_slug($wpdb)` function..

Comment: so you are using `$_GET['slug']` only if it is not set?

Comment: @mishu Good catch, should be `!isset($_GET['slug'])`

Comment: I know it should be !isset, but it doesn't work if I do that so for now I'm using just isset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified code. i hope it will work. if not let me know.

```
if (isset($_GET['slug'])){
    function get_slug() {
        $slug = 'home';
        return $slug;
    }
} else {
    function get_slug() {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "SELECT slug FROM wp_content WHERE slug='".$_GET['slug']."'";
        while ($result = $wpdb->get_results($sql)) {
            $slug = $result['slug'];
            return $slug;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Also, note that you shoudln't be concatenating something that came via $_GET to your SQL stament, that would be prone to SQL Injection. Try escaping or using prepared statements.

Comment: It took me sometime to figure out where it was modified. Using global is considered a [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1558073/2513523). You should advice passing the object to the function as mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Its because, `$wpdb;` is not accessible from inside your function.

If you add a language construct `global` to `$wpdb`, you will get this object.

[PHP Global Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)